# Не сохраняются сообщения в БД

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

require_once ('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

$msg = $_POST['msg'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$name'";
$resul = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($resul);

$id = $row['id'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO messages(id_user,message) VALUES ($id,'$msg')";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

echo 1;
```

}
else
{

echo 0;

}

Comment: Ребят извините Вопрос решен!

Comment: Ну тогда ответь на свой вопрос или удали его.